# Getting ofonod error in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10

I am getting error :-

```
ofonod[1044]: get_property_value: ERROR reply to Get
```

My Question is :-

1) How to solve this?

2) Repository says that it is for mobile device. Is it safe to remove in laptop?

**System Details:**

```
Ubuntu 17.10 Laptop
Model : Acer e 15 e5-575G-50zz
Intel:core i5 7220U
Nvidia 940MX
has bluetooth, webcam and wireless wifi devices.
builtin card reader
xorg gnome enviroment
```

**Error Logs:**

```
journalctl -p err -b
-- Logs begin at Sat 2017-12-30 18:33:49 IST, end at Sat 2017-12-30 18:50:47 IST
Dec 30 18:33:49 comp kernel: platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [
Dec 30 18:33:49 comp kernel: acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: 
Dec 30 18:34:05 comp ofonod[1044]: get_property_value: ERROR reply to Get
Dec 30 18:34:09 comp NetworkManager[1042]: ((src/devices/nm-device.c:1452)): ass
Dec 30 18:34:11 comp wpa_supplicant[1366]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties:
Dec 30 18:34:11 comp wpa_supplicant[1366]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
Dec 30 18:34:11 comp wpa_supplicant[1366]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp3
Dec 30 18:34:15 comp ofonod[1044]: get_property_value: ERROR reply to Get
Dec 30 18:34:21 comp gnome-session-binary[1429]: CRITICAL: Unable to create a DB
Dec 30 18:35:07 comp ofonod[1044]: get_property_value: ERROR reply to Get
lines 1-11/11 (END)...skipping...
-- Logs begin at Sat 2017-12-30 18:33:49 IST, end at Sat 2017-12-30 18:50:47 IST. --
Dec 30 18:33:49 comp kernel: platform MSFT0101:00: failed to claim resource 1: [mem 0xfed40000-0xfed40fff]
Dec 30 18:33:49 comp kernel: acpi MSFT0101:00: platform device creation failed: -16
Dec 30 18:34:05 comp ofonod[1044]: get_property_value: ERROR reply to Get
Dec 30 18:34:09 comp NetworkManager[1042]: ((src/devices/nm-device.c:1452)): assertion '<dropped>' failed
Dec 30 18:34:11 comp wpa_supplicant[1366]: dbus: wpa_dbus_get_object_properties: failed to get object properties: (none) none
Dec 30 18:34:11 comp wpa_supplicant[1366]: dbus: Failed to construct signal
Dec 30 18:34:11 comp wpa_supplicant[1366]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp3s0 flags: No such device
Dec 30 18:34:15 comp ofonod[1044]: get_property_value: ERROR reply to Get
Dec 30 18:34:21 comp gnome-session-binary[1429]: CRITICAL: Unable to create a DBus proxy for GnomeScreensaver: Error calling StartServiceByName 
Dec 30 18:35:07 comp ofonod[1044]: get_property_value: ERROR reply to Get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you can safely uninstall the Ofono package (assuming you're not using it for its intended purpose) with a call to `sudo apt-get purge ofono`. It's quite likely that the error generated was because, according to your system specs, you don't have a wireless radio that would use Ofono services (i.e., GSM/UMTS).

I'm curious about why you have this installed on your machine. Is (was) there a reason for installing [Ofono](https://01.org/ofono) initially (it's an interesting package)?